# Ubuntu 12.04 Ext4 ext4_dx_add_entry:2006: Directory index full!

Tags: 12.04, hard-drive, ext4

I'm having in some servers this warning, I have a directory with millions (20 more or less) of files but according to ext4 documentation this shouldn't be an issue.

Any idea how can this affect my systems? am I in danger to loose files?
is there any configuration to stop this behavior?

```
[1130768.836378] EXT4-fs warning (device dm-0): ext4_dx_add_entry:2006: Directory index full!
[1130768.836558] EXT4-fs warning (device dm-0): ext4_dx_add_entry:2006: Directory index full!
[1130768.836739] EXT4-fs warning (device dm-0): ext4_dx_add_entry:2006: Directory index full!
[1130768.836914] EXT4-fs warning (device dm-0): ext4_dx_add_entry:2006: Directory index full!
[1130769.881446] EXT4-fs warning (device dm-0): ext4_dx_add_entry:2006: Directory index full!
[1130769.881668] EXT4-fs warning (device dm-0): ext4_dx_add_entry:2006: Directory index full!
[1130769.881841] EXT4-fs warning (device dm-0): ext4_dx_add_entry:2006: Directory index full!
[1130769.881969] EXT4-fs warning (device dm-0): ext4_dx_add_entry:2006: Directory index full!
[1130769.882084] EXT4-fs warning (device dm-0): ext4_dx_add_entry:2006: Directory index full!
```

Output of `df -i`

```
Filesystem                             Inodes    IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/INTEGRASERVER02--vg-root 72179712 11081503 61098209   16% /
none                                  2049034        2  2049032    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev                                  2046225     1252  2044973    1% /dev
tmpfs                                 2049034     1237  2047797    1% /run
none                                  2049034        2  2049032    1% /run/lock
none                                  2049034        1  2049033    1% /run/shm
none                                  2049034        2  2049032    1% /run/user
/dev/sda1                               62248      298    61950    1% /boot
```

Comment: Try `df -i` on the partition containing the directory, and edit your question to add the output please, might be related to running out of inodes, though I'm not 100%.

Comment: yes, you are losing files. Each message is the failure to add a file to a directory.

Comment: I've added the output of the df -i only 16% used of the inodes

Comment: but is still generation new files it doesnt stop generating them

Answer (score 0):

Each message is the failure to add a file to a directory.

There is no official limit on the number of file entries in an ext4
directory, but there are 2 articles describing the original design (started in
ext2 in 2001) which state the following, and which are just as relevant for
ext4:

[Features found in Linux 2.6:](http://ext2.sourceforge.net/2005-ols/paper-html/node3.html)

> two levels of index nodes are sufficient to support over **16 million
>   52-character** filenames.

[A Directory Index for Ext2](http://web.archive.org/web/20131203105316/http://www.linuxshowcase.org/2001/full_papers/phillips/phillips_html/index.html)

> A second index level is required only for very large directories,which
>   can accommodate somewhat more than **30 million** entries.

If you are creating and removing files a lot in a directory, apparently
there may be space lost due to fragmentation in the filename strings which
you can recover by doing (on an unmounted filesystem):

```
fsck -D /dev/...
```

See man fsck.ext4:

> -D     Optimize  directories  in filesystem.  This option causes e2fsck
>          to try to optimize all directories, either by reindexing them if
>          the  filesystem  supports directory indexing,  or by sorting and
>          compressing directories for smaller directories, or for filesys-
>          tems using traditional linear directories.

Comment: The issue is not space, is that seems that ext4 doesnt suppot as many files on a single directory as is supposed to

Comment: @scgm11 That is what I am saying. It not about disk space, nor about inodes. It about a design choice made in the implementation of how filenames are stored in a directory structure in the filesystem. Depending on the length of your filenames you are limited in how many you may have in a directory. That is the space being discussed.

Comment: all files are uuid 36 chars plus dot and extension, so the best way should be using directories inside the main directory to ensure not to pass the limit?.

Comment: @scgm11 Yes, if you can. For example, use the first character of the filename as the name of the directory to put it in.

Comment: the strange thing is that new files are ok on the directory, is there any other way to fix this without using directories? any other configuration?

Comment: I dont know of any easy solutions. There must be other filesystem types that accept big directories, or often people resort to databases to hold huge amounts of data.